# Need Help in Android Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have gotten a project in which I want to select the data from spinners and than add the Edittext(in number) .After that there is Add More Button . When user click on it than yes or no option be selected . If user select yes than previous value be in textview , and user able to again use spinner and Edittext.
The previous value should be edittable . How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this tutorial to know how to implement Spinners:
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/android-spinner-tutorial/

Updating editText

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_box);
    editText.getText().toString();




}


public void addItemsOnSpinner()
{
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (this, R.array.spinner_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter (adapter);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner1, View view,int pos, long id)
{
         editText.setText(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
         editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

In XML: You should set visibility of editText to invisible or gone in XML, depends on what suits your needs better. then you can use following to make it appear :